# Show that the set of all cubic polynomials is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, vectors, alternative-proof

"Show that $p(t) = p_0 + p_1t + p_2t^2 + p_3t^3$ , where $t \in [a,b]$ and the coefficients $p_k$ are real scalars, forms a vector space. What is the dimension of this vector space? Explain"

How is it closed under addition? If you have $t_1$ and $t_2$, 
$p(t_1) + p(t_2) = 2p_0 + (t_1 + t_2) p_1 + ({t_1}^2 + {t_2}^2) p_2 + ({t_1}^3 + {t_2}^3) p_3$.

I apologize in advance for the terrible formatting. I'm new here, and I don't know how to format mathematically

Comment: You need to add functions, not values of a singlefunction. The vectors are the **functions** from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ defined by polynomials of degree at most $3$. If $p(t) = p_0 + p_1t + p_2t^2 +p_3t^3$ and $q(t) = q_0+q_1t+q_2t^2_+q_3t^3$, what is the sum of the function $p(t)$ and the function $q(t)$?

Comment: Search MathJax Tutorial in the Mathematics Meta site. As for the question, you were wrong about the form of elements that are involved in arithmetic operations.

Comment: If $p_3=0$, then the polynomial isn’t cubic. In particular, $0$ isn’t cubic, so it’s going to be hard to get a vector space. More properly, the set you’re asking about is polynomials of degree $\le3$.

Comment: @amd:  Here the cubic polynomials are considered to include lower degrees, so all is well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not supposed to take two different values for $t$, you are supposed to take two cubic polynomials in $t$, add them, and note that you get another cubic polynomial in $t$.  So you have $p(t)=p_0+p_1t+p_2t^2+p_3t^3$ and $q(t)=q_0+q_1t+q_2t^2+q_3t^3$.  What is $p(t)+q(t)?$  Is it a cubic polynomial in $t$?

Answer (score 1):

You're not meant to add two values of the same polynomial $p(t)$ and different times $t_1$ and $t_2$. The result would be a polynomial over those two indeterminates, which is not in the original vector space, as you say.

You're meant to add two polynomials having the same indeterminate $t$, let's say $p(t)=p_0+p_1t+p_2t^2+p_3t^3$ and $q(t)=q_0+q_1t+q_2t^2+q_3t^3$.