# Show that the set of all quadratic polynomials is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

I found a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3378924/show-that-the-set-of-all-cubic-polynomials-is-a-vector-space) but it is asking about cubic polynomials and I think everyone showed how to set up the problem, just not solve it.

The problem: $\mathcal{P}_2 = \{p_0 + p_1x + p_2x^2 : p_0,p_1,p_2\in\mathbb{R}\}$ be the set of all quadratic polynomials. (a) Show that it is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. (b) Show that $\{1, x, 2x^2 - 1\}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{P}_2$. (c) Find the components of the polynomial $2 + 4x + 4x^2$ with respect to this basis.

I think I would do something like this: Let $p(x) = p_0 + p_1x + p_2x^2$ and $q(x) = q_0 + q_1x + q_2x^2$ be two polynomials. We show closedness under addition:
$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}p(x) + q(x) &= (p_0 + p_1x + p_2x^2) + (q_0 + q_1x + q_2x^2) \\ &= (p_0 + q_0) + (p_1 + q_1)x + (p_2 + q_2)x^2 \in \mathcal{P}_2 \end{split}\end{equation}$$
We show closedness under scalar multiplication. Let $\alpha \in\mathbb{R}$. Then:
$$\alpha \cdot p(x) = \alpha(p_0 + p_1x + p_2x^2) = \alpha p_0 + \alpha p_1x + \alpha p_2x^2 \in\mathcal{P}_2 $$

Here is (b): Given the set of polynomials. Put their coefficients into a matrix we get
$$\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{matrix}\right]\sim\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$$
Thus this spans $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathcal{P}_2$ and is linearly independent set of vectors. Thus, it is a basis for $\mathcal{P}_2$.

For (c). Let $q(x) = 2 + 4x + 4x^2$. The basis matrix from our basis from part (b), call it $B$, is
$$B = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{matrix}\right] \implies B^{-1} = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{matrix}\right]$$
And finally, compute:
$$Bq(x) = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}2 \\ 4 \\ 4 \end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}-2 \\ 4 \\ 8 \end{matrix}\right]$$
Thus the components of the polynomial $q(x) = 2 + 4x + 4x^2$ is $\left[\begin{matrix}-2 \\ 4 \\ 8 \end{matrix}\right]$. Which gives us a new polynomial $-2 + 4x + 8x^2$.

I'd love all the constructive criticism I can get! Thank you!

Comment: That is correct. What about the other two questions?

Comment: I'll add them back in! But I wrote them out on my iPad, thus it will be a photo.

Comment: As stated, it’s slightly incorrect. Quadratic polynomials have $p_2\ne 0$. You mean all polynomials of degree at most 2.

Comment: The last sentence about the “new polynomial” is incorrect. You’re not changing the polynomial; you’re just writing in a different way.